# Converting FTP "ls -ltr" to SFTP

Tags: ftp, sftp, openssh

I was migrating an FTP functionality to SFTP. In shell script that does FTP, I saw some lines and I can not convert them to SFTP. I searched but couldn't get a result.

With `ftp`, I can get remote file names to local log file like this:

```
ftp>
cd remote_folder
ls -ltr local_file.tmp
```

With `sftp` (OpenSSH client) this doesn't work. It says *"file could not be found"* about `ls` command. And it also says `-t` or `-r` options are invalid with `ls` command. How can I do same thing with `sftp`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

We do not know what "ftp" client you were using. So it's hard to tell what the `ls -ltr` was doing. Though my guess is that your "ftp" client was transparently passing the switches to the FTP server, not processing them locally. Again, we do not know what FTP server you were using. But I know of only one FTP server that supports `-ltr` and that is ProFTPD. In ProFTPD the [`-ltr` means long directory listing sorted reversely by timestamp](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/ListOptions.html). The OpenSSH `sftp` client supports the same [switches for `ls` command with the very same meaning](https://man.openbsd.org/sftp#ls). If it is not working for you, you are probably using a *very* old version of OpenSSH. The `-tr` switches seem to be supported since OpenSSH 3.6 (February 2001) and the `-l` even longer.

OpenSSH `sftp` does not support writing the listing to a file. But you can redirect whole `sftp` output to a file.

Something like this:

```
sftp -b script.txt user@example.com > local_file.tmp
```

With `script.txt` containing:

```
cd remote_folder
ls -ltr
```